# Exponential Moving Average in php

Tags: php, math, exponential, weighted-average

I want to calculate the EMA (Exponential Moving Average) value in PHP.

I've tried with following code but it's giving me 500 error.

```
$real = array(12,15,17,19,21,25,28,12,15,16);
$timePeriod = 3;
$data = trader_ema($real,$timePeriod);
var_dump($data);
```

PHP: EMA calculation function [trader-ema](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trader-ema.php)

Tried with long time Googling but not getting any help on this in PHP. So, I've no clue what needs to be done to calculate the EMA value.

**Edit-1: Installed extensions**

I've installed all the necessary extensions, Now I am getting the output.
But it doesn't seems giving proper output.

I think PHP function for calculating EMA is not working properly.
Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 500 is a generic error code. Check logs for exact error message and update the question. It may be the case that the trader extension is not installed: http://php.net/manual/en/trader.installation.php

Comment: What's on `$array`?

Comment: @PatrickMlr: I've edited my question, It was by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for down vote, can you justify?

Comment: @Loading.. Did you delete my answer?

Comment: No man, I didn't seen any answers yet.

Comment: Dear @Loading.., please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to avoid further downvoting.  "it doesn't seems giving proper output" is not a problem statement.

Comment: @Alex Blex Thanks for your feedback, I just noticed that this php ema calculation function is not giving right output, may be it's giving weighted mean only.. so how I can calculate ema in php, is there any other functions available?

Comment: @Loading.. Please add expected and actual output to the question.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend to use the math library from:
https://github.com/markrogoyski/math-php

```
public static function exponentialMovingAverage(array $numbers, int $n): array
{
     $m   = count($numbers);
     $α   = 2 / ($n + 1);
     $EMA = [];

     // Start off by seeding with the first data point
     $EMA[] = $numbers[0];

     // Each day after: EMAtoday = α⋅xtoday + (1-α)EMAyesterday
     for ($i = 1; $i < $m; $i++) {
        $EMA[] = ($α * $numbers[$i]) + ((1 - $α) * $EMA[$i - 1]);
     }

     return $EMA;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trader extension for PHP actually looks quite promising. The underlying code looks very mature, and I notice at the time of writing the latest stable PHP module ([0.5.1](https://pecl.php.net/package/trader)) was released at the first of this year with support for PHP8.

It may take some reading of the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.trader.php), for example the note around [trader_set_unstable_period](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trader-set-unstable-period.php), and god-forbid, the [trader source code](https://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html) to become proficient.

If I do a quick installation of the trader module in a [PHP Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/php)

```sh
apt-get update
pecl install trader
docker-php-ext-enable trader
```

using the article from [here](https://school.stockcharts.com/doku.php?id=technical_indicators:moving_averages#ema_accuracy) as a benchmark

[image: ema-benchmark-numbers]

and put together a simple test script comparing the function supplied by @Tryke and [`trader_ema`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trader-ema.php)

```php
function exponentialMovingAverage(array $numbers, int $n): array
{
     $m   = count($numbers);
     $α   = 2 / ($n + 1);
     $EMA = [];

     // Start off by seeding with the first data point
     $EMA[] = $numbers[0];

     // Each day after: EMAtoday = α⋅xtoday + (1-α)EMAyesterday
     for ($i = 1; $i < $m; $i++) {
        $EMA[] = ($α * $numbers[$i]) + ((1 - $α) * $EMA[$i - 1]);
     }

     return $EMA;
}

function merge_results($input, $avgs) {
    $results = [];
    $empty = count($input) - count($avgs);
    foreach($input as $i => $price) {
        $results[] = $i < $empty ? [$price, null] : [$price, round($avgs[$i], 2)];
    }
    return $results;
}

$real = [
    22.27,
    22.19,
    22.08,
    22.17,
    22.18,
    22.13,
    22.23,
    22.43,
    22.24,
    22.29,
    22.15,
    22.39,
    22.38,
    22.61,
    23.36,
    24.05,
    23.75,
    23.83,
    23.95,
    23.63,
    23.82,
    23.87,
    23.65,
    23.19,
    23.10,
    23.33,
    22.68,
    23.10,
    22.40,
    22.17
];

$timePeriod = 10;
$traderData = trader_ema($real,$timePeriod);
echo "trader ema\n";
var_dump(merge_results($real, $traderData));


$phpData = exponentialMovingAverage($real, 3);
echo "\n\nphp ema\n";
var_dump(merge_results($real, $phpData));
```

The results of the `trader_ema` match exactly. The results from Tryke's function do not. It seems to have results starting on the first day, whereas my expectation (and the output of the `trader_ema` and benchmark numbers reflect) is that there are no results until the `$timePeriod` has elapsed. See this note from the [Investopedia article on EMA](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/ema.asp)

> Calculating the EMA requires one more observation than the SMA.
> Suppose that you want to use 20 days as the number of observations for
> the EMA. Then, you must wait until the 20th day to obtain the SMA. On
> the 21st day, you can then use the SMA from the previous day as the
> first EMA for yesterday.